# How do you break out of a Thread when it is in a loop?

Tags: ruby

I've run the following in irb but it doesn't break out/exit of the Thread when it is finished:

```
count = 0

Thread.new do
  while count < 20 do
    puts 'Hai'
    count += 1
  end
  Thread.kill
end
```

It just hangs there in the console. Is there a way to completely exit out of the thread? From what I've researched the Thread should end after it exits the block but I couldn't find any information about this online. Thanks!

Comment: Are not You just confused by what the console is diplaying?

Comment: Can you run that block I posted above? After the 20th "Hai" it doesn't exit

Comment: Your prompt is back after you defined your thread. Your main thread (prompt) and the thread you created are not the same.

Comment: the prompt comes back but I am not back in the console > .  It is just giving me a blinking cursor and I need to do a CTRL-C to exit back to the irb >

Comment: @perseverance the thread just flooded your console, that's why you cannot see your prompt (it's somewhere between the `Hai`'s). Try to enter something or hit return.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the small example, May it will help you.

```
begin
  t = Thread.new do
    loop do
      @bar.increment!
      STDERR.flush
      sleep 1
    end
  end
  yield
  STDERR.puts ' done!' unless $?.exitstatus > 0
rescue => e
  STDOUT.puts "Error:"
  STDOUT.puts e.message
ensure
  t.kill
end
```